# Posts is missing in wordpress admin

Tags: wordpress

In my WordPress admin it shows that I have 0 posts, 0 comments, tags, categories etc, but when I visit the site there are posts.

Answer (score 1):

That might happen because you are not logging in as the admin user or the user that has posted the posts. Make sure you have chosen the right user. If that's not your problem, can you give us some additional information? Which version do you use? Which plugins are active? Have you tried to deactivate all plugins to find out if some plugin causes the issue?

Comment: im the only user of my blog.. anyway its working now i contacted the hosts their doing some maintenance..